# What is the C# equivalent of Rawinput in Python?

Tags: c#, raw-input

What is the C# equivalent of Rawinput in Python?

How do I read user input in a C# Console Application?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx

Comment: Don't write fluff in your questions, it makes no difference if you just moved on from python or not.  Stick to just the question itself.  And there's no need to write Hi, thanks, etc either.

Comment: Alright, I got my answer!

Comment: Glad you got what you were looking for. Can you please use the tick next to one answer to mark it as accepted so others don't come here to solve a solved problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
Console.ReadLine()
```

or for one character

```
Console.ReadKey()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the reference

[Console.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Console.ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx)